# Show categories in random order

Tags: categories, tags

I'm using categories as tags for news articles and showing a list of "tags" in the sidebar. I'd like the list of "tags" to be ordered randomly. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: no concrete solution, but you could fetch the category list, and jumble it with jquery. If you want to do it server side, you could get a list and feed it for instance to the low-random add-on, http://gotolow.com/addons/low-random/docs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For showing categories you can use "GWCode Categories" plugin which is having "orderby" parameter with "random" value. Like:

```
{exp:gwcode_categories orderby="random"}
{category_name}
{/exp:gwcode_categories}
```

Comment: glad to help you ... :)